# Why does java.net.SocketInputStream not exist?

Tags: java, sockets, java-io

I am learning Java IO and Socket, and got confused by what does *socket.getInputStream()* actually returns...

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
System.out.println(is.getClass().getName());
```

Since InputStream is an abstract class, socket.getInputStream() must return an instantiated child class of the InputStream. I use the above code the get the actual class name, but *is.getClass().getName()* turns out to be

```
java.net.SocketInputStream
```

I tried to import this class in Eclipse and found no this class...

So what actually happened? Do I misunderstand some part of Java?

Comment: If you read the javadocs you will see *Direct Known Subclasses:
AudioInputStream, ByteArrayInputStream, FileInputStream, FilterInputStream, InputStream, ObjectInputStream, PipedInputStream, SequenceInputStream, StringBufferInputStream*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class is [package-private](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). You can't refer to it directly from outside the `java.net` package.

Comment: Is there any way for me to see the source code of this class?

Comment: @JingHe Sure, it's in the source code zip. It extends `FileInputStream` interestingly enough, via the `FileDescriptor` constructor, and it has some stuff to close the socket along with the stream. Otherwise nothing of interest there, move along.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to import this class in Eclipse and found no this class...

The class exists but it is **package-private** only, so **not** public.
That means you can only use it when your class is also inside the same package (`java.net`). Here is a small overview of the [access controls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

It is obviously inside the package `java.net` and is called `SocketInputStream`. It is a regular class that extends from `FileInputStream`.

Here is the source code: [SocketInputStream at GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/net/SocketInputStream.java)

And here is the [documentation](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/net/SocketInputStream.html). To quote from it:

> This stream extends FileInputStream to implement a SocketInputStream. Note that this class should NOT be public.